# how to find specific information from string in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, json

I have case how to find, how many
people who have an age equal to or greater than 50 from this notation in nodeJS

```
"key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88, key=4SCsU, age=65, key=q3kG6, age=33, key=MGQpf, age=13"
```

Comment: This is neither a proper string or an object. Please check your string and format it properly.

Comment: I know it,
but this string notation as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29, key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88, key=4SCsU, age=65, key=q3kG6, age=33, key=MGQpf, age=13";

let arr = str.split(', ');
let count = 0;
arr.forEach(e => {
  let key = e.split('=')[0];
  let val = e.split('=')[1];
  if(key == "age"){
    if(val >= 50)
      count++;
  }
})
console.log(count)
```